# Reducing the frame size of a uiviewcontroller being presented modally with option UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am recreating a popup style view controller. 
In the implementation below I am instantiating a view controller and then presenting it on its parent VC modally using the option `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`.

I would like to reduce the frame size so as to make the new viewcontroller  appear more like a popup but the frame size keeps getting overwritten. I also tried setting the frame size of the viewcontroller in its `-viewWillAppear` and `-viewDidLoad` methods but nothing changes. Any thoughts?

```
UIStoryboard* popStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"XXX" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* popViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"XXXXXX"];

popViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
popViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 450);

[[self topMostViewController] presentViewController:popViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: Subclass UIView, create custom UIView to be the view controller's view, load view in "loadview" method, in custom subclass, resize the view to your liking by adding other uiviews and what not ... win

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a view controller with a pointer variable named `popViewController` but you changing the view's frame and presenting a pointer variable named `viewController`.

Comment: Nice catch. That isn't actually the problem though. I had to change my code before pasting it on here and I hadn't renamed the last two statements.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a typo or something.